# Optimal transport - Earth mover's distance

Tags: optimal-transport

I want to calculate the distance between two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ over the compact set $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$, using the Wasserstein formula:

$$W=\inf_\varphi\int|x-y|\,{\rm d}\varphi(x,y),$$

where $\varphi$ is interpreted as a transport plan satisfying $\int\varphi(x,y)dy=\mu(x)$ and $\int\varphi(y,x)dy=\nu(x)$.

The particularity of my problem is that I know that $\nu$ is obtained from $\mu$ by moving mass to the right. More specifically, there exists a nondecreasing onto function $t:[a,b]\rightarrow[a,b]$ with $t(a)=a$ and $t(b)=b$ such that

$$
\nu(t(x))=\mu(x),\quad\text{for all $x\in[a,b]$.}
$$

Then, can we say that $t$ corresponds to an optimal transport plan? That is, is the plan
$$
\varphi^*(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\mu(x)&\text{if $y=t(x)$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
optimal?

Thank you!